# Obtaining URL in WPF WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net

I have been working in WPF web browsers lately but I can't seem to be able to get URIs out of it. (Unlike the WinForms version which has the WebBrowser.Url property). Is there any property that holds it either it's as Uri or String?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to refer to the `WebBrowser.Source` property that holds the `Uri` object associated to the current view. Take a look to [Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.source.aspx).