# Get Source from WebBrowser WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am in the process of building a WPF application with a WebBrowser component.
I am having issues getting the Source URI from the WebBrowser.
I have researched here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.source.aspx and checked this past question here: [Obtaining URL in WPF WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273409/obtaining-url-in-wpf-webbrowser) 
However this has not helped.
The answer on that question states to use the `WebBrowser.Source` property and I have used (`browser` being the name given to my WebBrowser component) `browser.Source.ToString()` however, no matter what I try, I keep getting error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
>   System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser.Source.get returned null.

Here is a code example:

```
public LoginWindow() //Called when window is opened
{
    InitializeComponent();
    browser.Navigating += Browser_Navigating;
    Main.log(browser.Source.ToString());
}
private void Browser_Navigating(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (browser.Source.IsLoopback)
        {
            Main.log("Looped Back");
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes I have. The source is set already and works fine. The only problem is getting the value Source property.

Comment: You need to post a [Minimal valid Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to help. In fact creating a MVCE often shows you the problem.

Comment: Pretty sure I explained it well enough but I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It throws exception because you didn't navigate to any page yet, so source is not available.

Add logging in `Navigated` event.

```
private void webBrowser_Navigated (object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Log (webBrowser.Source.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why everyone else had to make getting this answer so difficult.